# How to split a String("dog") to an Arraylist ['d', 'o', 'g']?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, converters

I have an input **`String`** and I want its letters to be in an **`ArrayList`**. Like `"abc"` to `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

I've tried `split()` method but its error is  `Cannot resolve method 'asList(java.lang.String[])'`

```
userInput = scanner.next();
inputLetters = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.<Character>asList(userInput.split("")));
```

I have java 13 so this should have work

Comment: Having `ArrayList<Character>` is unusual which makes your question look like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Normally when we want to gather some characters we use `String` or `char[]`. Can you explain why you think you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused because `userInput.split("")` produces `["a","b","c"]` which is a String array instead of the expected `['a','b','c']` which is a char array.

A simple workaround is:

1. Split string to char array
2. Create an empty arrayList
3. Iterate through char array and add it to the arrayList

```
String userInput = "abc";
char[] inputCharArray = userInput.toCharArray();
List<Character> userList = new ArrayList<>();
for(char c: inputCharArray)
    userList.add(c);
```

Answer (score 5):

When you pass a `String[]` to `Arrays.asList()`, you'll get a `List<String>`, not a `List<Character>`.

You can convert your `List<String>` to a `List<Character>` as follows:

```
List<Character> inputLetters = Arrays.asList(userInput.split(""))
                                     .stream()
                                     .map(s -> s.charAt(0))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another way to get a `List<Character>`:

```
List<Character> inputLetters = userInput.chars()
                                        .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, if you don't mind working with a `char[]` instead of a `List<Character>`, simply use `userInput.toCharArray()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use toCharArray .Here is the example code

```
String userInput = "abc";

        for (char c : userInput.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
```

Comment: Far simpler. Had posted same code more or less! Will let you have this.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
public static ArrayList<Character> convertStringToList(String s){
    ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars){
        list.add(c);
    }
    return list;
}
```

The code just converts the String to a char[] and iterates through the array, forming the list.